# Dataset: time-series classification in social networks

Tags: classification, network-structure

I need a dataset concerning a task in social network time-series classification. Please let me know if you had any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

To get started

#### [Stanford Large Network Dataset Collection](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/)

```
Social networks : online social networks, edges represent interactions between people
Networks with ground-truth communities : ground-truth network communities in social and information networks
Communication networks : email communication networks with edges representing communication
Citation networks : nodes represent papers, edges represent citations
Collaboration networks : nodes represent scientists, edges represent collaborations (co-authoring a paper)
Web graphs : nodes represent webpages and edges are hyperlinks
Amazon networks : nodes represent products and edges link commonly co-purchased products
Internet networks : nodes represent computers and edges communication
Road networks : nodes represent intersections and edges roads connecting the intersections
Autonomous systems : graphs of the internet
Signed networks : networks with positive and negative edges (friend/foe, trust/distrust)
Location-based online social networks : social networks with geographic check-ins
Wikipedia networks, articles, and metadata : talk, editing, voting, and article data from Wikipedia
Temporal networks : networks where edges have timestamps
Twitter and Memetracker : memetracker phrases, links and 467 million Tweets
Online communities : data from online communities such as Reddit and Flickr
Online reviews : data from online review systems such as BeerAdvocate and Amazon
User actions : actions of users on social platforms.
Face-to-face communication networks : networks of face-to-face (non-online) interactions
Graph classification datasets : disjoint graphs from different classes
```

---

[Center for Machine Learning and Intelligent Systems](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.php?format=&task=&att=&area=&numAtt=10to100&numIns=&type=ts&sort=nameUp&view=table)